# Convert unicode value to string in java

Tags: java, unicode

I am trying to extract currencies in my texts and I am getting currencies from db which contains special currency symbols as well. For example for the pound, I have unicode of pound "\u00A3" in the db along with other identifiers such as "gbp" as well.

I am trying to get the corresponding symbol from the unicode and compare with my text in a loop as suggested in [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/ConvertfromUTF8toUnicode.htm).

But when I evaluate my code, the result is like in the image here:
[image: the result]

```
private Optional<Currency> extractTokenWise(Iterable<String> tokens){
    try {
        for (String aToken : tokens) {
            for (String currency : currencies.keySet()) {
                for (String arep : currencies.get(currency)) {
                    if(arep.startsWith("\\")){ //special character for currency written in unicode representation                  
                        byte[] charset = arep.getBytes("UTF-8");
                        arep = new String(charset, "UTF-8");
                    }
                    if (aToken.equals(arep)) {
                        return Optional.of(Currency.findProperEnum(currency));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

It is interesting that when `arep` is equal to `"\u00A3"`, it does not work but when I specifically give `String` value of `"\u00A3"`, It produces the result I want.  What am I missing here?

Comment: You've misunderstood what the demo code does, and what `"\u00A3"` means in Java code. The demo code converts a String of chars to a byte array using UTF-8 encoding, and then it converts the UTF-8 encoded byte array back to the original string again. The resulting string is thus exactly identical to what it orginally started with. It's just a demo showing how to convert from one to the other; it's not telling you to put those two statements one after the other. Now, in Java source code the string literal `"\u00A3"` is exactly one character long. It's just another way of writing `"£"`.

Comment: What you need to do is find a way to parse `\u` when read from the database, recognise it as the start of a 4-digit hex number representing a character, and then read the hex digits into a number (preferably a char). There must be enough samples for this on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments something like this should work:

```
if (arep.startsWith("\\u")) {
        arep = Character.toString((char) Integer.parseInt(arep.substring(2), 16));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mix up unicode **escape sequences** in java code with **strings containing** such escape sequences.

`String poundSign = "\u00A3";` assigns `poundSign` a string containing the **single character £**. This string has a length of 1 character. In memory and in the class file it will occupy 2 bytes.

It looks like `arep` contains **the string `\u00A3`** as assigned by `String unicodeEscapeForPoundSign = "\\u00A3";` -- that's what your first if statement tests for. It contains the **unicode escape sequence** as used in java code, but not the character this escape sequence **represents**. It contains the 6 characters '\', 'u', '0', '0', 'A', and '3' (as your IDE shows). `arep.getBytes("UTF-8");` returns an array of just these characters and `new String(charset, "UTF-8");` converts the array back to the string `\u00A3` and **not** the string `£`

The solution depends on **what you get from your database**. Assuming you have a mapping from the db-value to a `Currency` object or the ISO currency code, you **won't need** your first if statement, just make sure `arep` contains the correct string:

- `String arep = "\u00A3"` (single pound character)
- `String arep = "\\u00A3"` (pound character java unicode escape string)

Comment: The "£" character will occupy 2 bytes in both UTF-8 and UTF-16.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException correct, thanks for the hint, I updated my answer. I was misled by the single byte code in latin1.